# List folders and sub folders of a git branch without checking out from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins-plugins, gerrit, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, opengrok

How can i achieve the solution by not using any git commands and use only APIs or plugins and list the directories and file content of particular git branch without checking out to the branch

I have used `git ls-tree` and `git show` commands to list the directories and subdirectories of a git branch and view the file content without checking out to the branch and by tracking all git branches by looping the branches that are listed under `git branch -r`

This execution is done on Jenkins Pipeline job and same steps and on same repository multiple jobs will be running due to that while using git commands it says other git process is running.

To avoid this situation i want to use either Gitiles or OpenGrok in jenkins but there is no proper plugin which will do it straight forward in Jenkins Pipeline.